# How to modify a properties file via portlet conf tab in liferay?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

I have a custom portlet which use 2 parameters I wrote in my portlet-conf.properties.

So, I would like change them if I want, by enters two new values into my setup tab, in configuration menu of the portlet.

Tab setup : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/155/samplesz.png/

I have my Controller and jsp for my portlet, and a conf.jsp and ConfigurationActionImpl which implements render returning conf.jsp and processAction empty for now, for the tab.

How can I code my jsp and my configAction for have 2 input text which can modify my two parameters in my portlet-conf.properties?

I want, when we click on the submit button, that change the value in a varaible on my property file.
If possible, display a default value in the input box, with the actual value.

Regards.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can overwrite the property values, just like that. The property file should be used as the portlet configuration.

You must use `PortletPreferences` for the same.

What you can do is that in your `conf.jsp`, create 2 input box and submit button. When you click submit button, `processAction()` of your `ConfigurationActionImpl` will be called. Here in this method, get the `PortletPreferences` and save the values into them.

The properties file will be used as the default values of the preferences. So, the flow would be

1) When user comes first time on the configuration of the portlet, you will get the null values in the portlet preferences, so load from the properties file.

2) User can change the values and when he/she clicks the submit button, save that into `PortletPreferences`

3) Next time, take the values from the `PortletPreferences`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Sure we can't modify a value of a variable on a property file? Because, my portlet use " @Value("${mss.portlet.myportlet.config.url}")" to get the value which is in a property file. We can't target them and modify them?

Comment: not sure on this one, but if you look at the liferay builtin portlets, then conf of portlet always uses portletPreferences, because it stored into database and that will be exported when you do publish to live or publish to remote.

Comment: Your method surely works and i'll test it, maybe someone knows if i can change the property like i want. Thanks

Comment: Please, how do i get the portletPreferences in my portletcontroller? config.jsp and confiactionimpl works fine, but now, how i get yhe portletpreferences that i will use in my portletcontroller? thank you.

Comment: Hi Jean, you will get the portlet preferences from the portletRequest it self, please use the getPreferences() method of the same.